# Create a form by article or component in Joomla! 3

Tags: joomla, components, article

I'm newbie in Joomla. I know that we can create a form like "Create Article" in joomla! . However, we can also create a form by creating a component with MVC method. What is the different ? 
Can somebody explain to me why we need a component if we can write a code on article in Joomla! ?

Comment: What do you mean by `create a form like "Create Article"`. Do you mean you can put `form` markup in an article? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a form in Joomla you can't make it as a standard content item. The editor will not allow it and filling out the form would not do anything. If you are talking about simply coding a flat html file and linking to it, you are kind of missing the whole point of using a CMS, and maintaining it in the future will be a hassle.

If all you need is an email sent when people fill out the form then you should be able to use one of these form builders:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms

If you need to store and use the entered data you will  probably need to build your own component. You could use the Component Creator for that if you have experience developing in PHP:

http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/